# AWS SNS console crashes while importing Registration IDs

Tags: amazon-web-services, import, amazon-sns

I want to import more than 80,000 token IDs in AWS SNS. When I read the condition it is mentioned that the file size should not be more than 2MB and it should be a CSV file. So I divided my file in such a way each file is 1.4 - 1.6 MB. Now when I tried to import my CSV file to AWS SNS console, it keeps crashing maybe because of the number of Registration IDs.

It says

> script stopped executing

But when I tried adding just 5-6 tokens it works perfectly fine.

Presently I have 4 CSV files with 20,000 Registration IDs. How should I deal with this problem ?

Comment: You don't really have 20.000 IDs in 1.6KB file :)? Perhaps MB (since AWs docs also mention `The CSV file cannot be larger than 2MB`) ?

Comment: Sorry it's MB. Typo Error. Let me edit it .